# how to save xml file with ajax and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I am new to using ajax. Now I have a project to create a localhost chatbox web page. And I want to save XML document using javascript. Here is my XML file.

```
<root>
<msg>Mesage 1</msg>
<msg>Message 2</msg>
</root>
```

Here is my javascript Code.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var doc;
xhttp.open("POST","det.xml");
xhttp.send(null);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        doc = xhttp.responseXML;
        var elem = doc.createElement("msg");
        elem.textContent = "Hello XML";
        doc.documentElement.appendChild(elem);
    }
};
```

But after run this web XML document has no changed. Please tell me how to save xml using ajax. Thanks in advance. And sorry for my poor english.

Comment: do you want to _load_ the XML into your DOM or save the XML to a file?

Comment: I want to read XML file and save it current file.Not a new file

Comment: so you don't want to do any file manipulation? It sounds like you want to display whatever is in the XML

Comment: save existing file?or want to download?

Comment: You have to send updated data to server and write to file there using a server side programming language

Comment: Thats is too low. Cant i do it with ajax ?

Comment: Yes...you can send data to server using ajax. Javascript in browser can't write anything on your server

Comment: Or use a cloud storage like firebase instead of using xml